# Visual Studio: Can I export parameter values from debug flow to unit test data inputs?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, debugging

For instance, I've got a complex function `Foo(ObjectA a, ObjectB b)` where `a` and `b` take a substantial amount of time to compose (because they're coming from a non-local server that cannot be localized for testing purposes), I'd love to be able to snatch these guys up in Visual Studio debug and say, here, make me a unit test or something where I can quickly load these values up again statically.

Thanks!

--edit-- 
we're definitely assuming that the a and b are serializable or something, where they'll be stored off in some persistent data storage file, and retrieved when the unit test starts up.

Comment: K, I guess the burden of responsibility falls to me to build this then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a workaround I could provide:

You could export the object value during debugging with certain extension tool like Object Exporter, and then read the file with database or others in your unit test(data driven unit test).

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OmarElabd.ObjectExporter

But whether the saved value was refreshed before the unit test calls the saving file, it would be a testing issue. Hope it could provide a path for you.

Comment: Magnificent.  Thanks Jack

Comment: This plugin crashes VS2015